# A couple of questions about optimising code for speed in C#

Tags: c#, optimization

If I have a method that is called many times, such as:

```
public int CalledManyTimes(int a, int b)
{
     MyObject myObject = new myObject();
     int c = a + b + myObject.GetSomeValue();

     return c;
}
```

Is there a performance boost by putting `MyObject myObject;` outside of the method, so it's only declared once, or will the compiler do this automatically?

How exactly are structs passed around?

I'm passing in a Point struct to a method (Point contains only int x, int y), and that method is altering the value and returning a `new Point(newX, newY);` Is it better to alter the Point that was passed into the method and return that? Or can I create a `Point point`; outside the method as proposed in my first question and use that?

Comment: have you measured and determined you actually have a performance problem?

Comment: Have you profiled your code? Do you really need these micro optimizations?

Comment: I don't have any performance issues as such, I just wrote a method that is called repeatedly in a loop for the duration of the program and wondered if declaring many variables as in the first example was a bad practice.

Comment: You said point was a struct, so usually you'll want it to be immutable.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but why rely on the compiler instead of writing the best code in the first place? `myObject` doesn't seem to change during the loop - so create it once outside the method and that's it. Also, if you can pass `ref Point` and modify it, then you won't need the `new Point` overhead. Even if it's 2-3 cycles, in real-time applications this could sum up to.. a lot.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`myObject` appears to have no useful state; so: make that a `static` method - problem solved; no allocation, no virtual call:

```
public int CalledManyTimes(int a, int b)
{
     int c = a + b + MyObject.GetSomeValue(); // static method

     return c;
}
```

For anything else: profile.

Looking at your specific questions:

> Is there a performance boost by putting MyObject myObject; outside of the method, so it's only declared once, or will the compiler do this automatically?

Initializing it zero times is even faster. However, if there *is* some state that isn't obvious in the question, then yes, I would expect it to be more efficient to reuse a single instance - however, that changes the semantic (in the original the state is not shared between iterations).

> How exactly are structs passed around?

By default, they are copied on the stack as soon as you so much as glance in their direction. You can use `ref` to avoid the copy, which may be useful if the struct is massively overweight, or need to be updated (ideally with reassignment, rather than mutability).

Comment: small note: there's no real benefit removing the `c` - the compiler can do that perfectly well itself in an optimized build; but with the `c` in place it is often easier to debug.

Comment: So garbage collection won't re-use an object, it'll always delete it? I guess if my method is being called 50 times per second then I should try to move as many object declarations outside the method as possible then (and make them static if required). As for structs, I guess the same rule applies. The case of structs, the method is basically, here's an x coordinate, give me a new x co-ordinate back. I can't `ref` it as I will want to compare the result, so it was `return new myStruct(x)` vs `passedInStruct.X = x`, `return passedInStruct;`

Comment: @SLC, 50 times a second? In this case you can write almost any code without measurable impact. Try and measure - [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) is enough for most cases.

Comment: @SLC no, an object is never automatically reused; and indeed, 50 times a second is nothing